# How to use bind_result to store sum of array values from a sql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm trying to get the total number of votes from the column name 'noOfVotes' for 3 different candidates. I'm using the query below, but I'm only getting the sum of the total votes of only the first candidate, using bind_result. Is there a way to use bind_result to store array values?
Please, help!

See code snippet here:

```
// Display Presidential Candidates Results
public function displayPresdentialCandidatesResults($Id){
    print_r($Id);
    if(!empty($Id)){
        // foreach($Id as $cand_id){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($Id); $i++){
            $cand_id = $Id[$i];
            echo "<br>" . $cand_id;
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT SUM(noOfVotes) AS totalVotes FROM resultstbl WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $pId);
            $pId = $cand_id;
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($totalVotes);
            $votes = array();
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                $votes[] = $totalVotes;
            }
            if(!empty($votes)){
                return $votes;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetchColumn to get all count votes instead of bind_result:

```php
// Display Presidential Candidates Results
public function displayPresdentialCandidatesResults($Id){
    print_r($Id);
    $votes = [];
    if(!empty($Id)){
        // foreach($Id as $cand_id){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($Id); $i++){
            $cand_id = $Id[$i];
            echo "<br>" . $cand_id;
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT SUM(noOfVotes) AS totalVotes FROM resultstbl WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $pId);
            $pId = $cand_id;
            $stmt->execute();
            $votes[] = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row()[0];
      
        }

       if(!empty($votes)){
         return $votes;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message at the console

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchColumn() in C:\xampp\htdocs\e-voting\voter_class.php:202 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\e-voting\live_results.php(10): voter_class->displayPresdentialCandidatesResults(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\e-voting\voter_class.php on line 202

Comment: I changed my answer. You are using mysqli. Fetch column have been using with only PDO driver.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm still getting the total number of votes of only one candidate returned out of the 3 candidates

Comment: Oh okay. Because, your if condition was inside of for condition. I have changed my answer pleas look at here.

Comment: Taking the if condition outside the forloop, the result returns 0 for all the three candidates.

The correct result should be 5votes for the first candidate, 0vote for the second and third candidates, as contained in the database

Comment: It's using the result of the last candidate for the first and second candidate too. That's why it's repeating 0s for the 3 candidates. I feel I'm doing something slightly wrong but I can't figure it out right now